# Join only first row with HQL

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

Is it possible to join only first row (or just any other row but only one) using hql?

```
select 
 config.id, mg.modelGroupName, min(deliveryType.id) 
from 
 NotificationConfig config, NotificationConfigEntry configEntry, SettlementModelGroup mg 
join 
 configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.user user 
join 
 configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.deliveryType deliveryType 
join 
 config.notificationType notifType 
join 
 notifType.objectType objectType 
where 
 config.id = configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.notificationConfig.id 
 and ( mg.modelId = config.objectId or config.objectId is null )
```

This is the code i'm having right now, of course

```
min(deliveryType.id)
```

doesn't work. Relation between mg.modelId and config.objectId is not mapped, and deliveryType is a list. I can't use distinct cause I need to be able to order by deliveryType (this won't make any sense, but i need to make it anyway) and modelGroupName.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 config.id, mg.modelGroupName, deliveryType.id 
from 
 NotificationConfig config, NotificationConfigEntry configEntry, SettlementModelGroup mg 
join 
 configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.user user 
join 
 configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.deliveryType deliveryType with deliveryType.id = (select min(id) from configEntry.notificationConfigEntryPK.deliveryType)
...
```